# Redux state.subscribe returns pointers

Tags: redux, immutability

I'm building a redux app. In my state I have the following:

```
{
name:string,
address:{...}
}
```

When i'm doing subscribe to the state I'm getting them both.
The problem is that when I'm modifying the address property on my component it changes also on store. After a little dig I found out that's because address is an object and it's returns pointer and not a copy.

My question is how can I subscribe to the store and not been afraid of massing the store?

Doing object.assign inside my subscribe function does the work but it feels kind of wired..

```
this.addressModel = Object.assign({},state.information.address);
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- First, if you're using React, you generally won't need to subscribe to the store "manually".  The `connect` function provided by the React-Redux package generates wrapper components that handle the subscription process for you.
- Second, yes, your reducer logic should always update data immutably.  This means ensuring that *every* level of nesting is copied.

The Redux FAQ [talks about immutability](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering) in relation to React components not re-rendering.  The Redux docs section on [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) includes [links to articles teaching about immutable data management](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html), as well as [how to properly update data immutably](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html).  I also have links to several other [articles on immutable data concepts](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md) as part of my React/Redux links list.